# Keep written " SQL Statement ignored" and "not enough values"

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my code:

```
declare
    cursor c1 is
        select * from PUTRAJAYA.STRATA_PJ_BORANG4
            WHERE HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL is NOT NULL;
   
      err_num   number;
        err_msg   varchar2(250);
      
      begin
    for c1rec in c1 loop
  
  BEGIN
                insert into ET_MAIN_WPPJ_JOZRIN.IND_HKMLK
                        (HKMLK_ID, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_BY, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, VERSION, 
            ID_HAKMILIK,NO_HAKMILIK, NO_BANGUNAN,NO_TINGKAT,NO_PETAK,UPI,FLAG_GANTUNG,
            FLAG_TUKARGANTI,TARIKH_KUTIPAN_ETANAH
                        )
                values (
                        SEQ_HKMLK.NEXTVAL,'DMS', SYSDATE, 'DMS', SYSDATE,'0', 
            (select substr(HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL,1,17),
            substr(HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL,-8) from strata_PJ_BORANG4),
          --  substr(STRATA_PJ_BORANG4.HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL,1,17),
          --  substr(STRATA_PJ_BORANG4.HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL,-8),
            (SELECT 
            HM_DETAIL_NOBGN,
            HM_DETAIL_NOTKT, 
            HM_DETAIL_NOPETAK,
            HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL,
            'N','N',
            HM_DETAIL_PUNGUT_DATETIME
            FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG1 A, STRATA_PJ_BORANG4 B
            WHERE A.DAF_HM_NOFAIL = B.HM_DETAIL_NOFAIL));

        END;
END LOOP;
END;
```

This the errors:

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 18, column 5: PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not
> enough values ORA-06550: line 13, column 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement
> ignored
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. The errors though core from *Oracle*. Which database are you using?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error suggests, and looking at line 18? What line *is* line 18?

Comment: SQL is a set-oriented language. It *doesn't* need loops or cursors, those were introduced for compatibility with 1970-80s mainframes. They can be useful in some *very* limited cases. This isn't one of them. You could write `INSERT (A,B,C) SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM .....` to insert one query's results directly into a table. This would be N times faster than the loop, and far easier to write, maintain and optimize

Comment: Along with "updating" to set based methods, it's also long past time to drop that 30+ year old syntax, and "update" tom the **1992** explicit `JOIN` syntax. You also seem to have a major design flaw with 2 tables named `STRATA_PJ_BORANG1` and `STRATA_PJ_BORANG4` respectively (as 2 tables with the same name suggests a denormalised designed), and I highly recommend using **appropriate** aliases. "A" is not for "STRATA_PJ_BORANG1" and "B" is not for "STRATA_PJ_BORANG4".

Comment: These are SQL Server articles, but the points still stand: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3), and just incase you think to use a `WHILE` instead: [Bad Habits to Kick : Thinking a WHILE loop isn't a CURSOR](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor)

Comment: What is the use of the cursor ? Can you please let us know what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos--Oracle database

Comment: @Larnu. I tried many ways.  I am newbies in Oracle/SQL language.  I dont have any guidance. I learn all from online.  This project been assigned to me from office. If I cant perform this script, I will be dismiss.

Comment: @Tejash. My aim is to insert the values into IND_HKMLK(table) at this database (ET_MAIN_WPPJ_JOZRIN).

Answer (score 0):

First of all lets try to understand the meaning of the error "not enough values". It suggest that for some column in the insert into claues value has not been provided in values clause. In your case insert into has 15 columns but values clause have only 8 values.I have re written your subqueries in value clause. Please try to execute this and see if this works fine for you.

```
declare
    cursor c1 is
        select * from PUTRAJAYA.STRATA_PJ_BORANG4
            WHERE HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL is NOT NULL;
   
      err_num   number;
        err_msg   varchar2(250);
      
      begin
    for c1rec in c1 loop
  
  BEGIN
                insert into ET_MAIN_WPPJ_JOZRIN.IND_HKMLK (
                HKMLK_ID, 
                CREATED_BY, 
                CREATED_DATE, 
                LAST_MODIFIED_BY, 
                LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, 
                VERSION, 
                ID_HAKMILIK,
                NO_HAKMILIK, 
                NO_BANGUNAN,
                NO_TINGKAT,
                NO_PETAK,
                UPI,
                FLAG_GANTUNG,
                FLAG_TUKARGANTI,
                TARIKH_KUTIPAN_ETANAH
                )
                values (
               SEQ_HKMLK.NEXTVAL,
               'DMS', 
               SYSDATE, 
               'DMS', 
               SYSDATE,
               '0', 
            (select substr(HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL,1,17) from strata_PJ_BORANG4),
            (select substr(HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL,-8) from strata_PJ_BORANG4),
          --  substr(STRATA_PJ_BORANG4.HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL,1,17),
          --  substr(STRATA_PJ_BORANG4.HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL,-8),
            (SELECT HM_DETAIL_NOBGN FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG1 A, STRATA_PJ_BORANG4 B WHERE A.DAF_HM_NOFAIL = B.HM_DETAIL_NOFAIL),
            (SELECT HM_DETAIL_NOTKT FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG1 A, STRATA_PJ_BORANG4 B WHERE A.DAF_HM_NOFAIL = B.HM_DETAIL_NOFAIL),
            (SELECT HM_DETAIL_NOPETAK FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG1 A, STRATA_PJ_BORANG4 B WHERE A.DAF_HM_NOFAIL = B.HM_DETAIL_NOFAIL),
            (SELECT HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG1 A, STRATA_PJ_BORANG4 B WHERE A.DAF_HM_NOFAIL = B.HM_DETAIL_NOFAIL),
            'N',
            'N',
            SELECT HM_DETAIL_PUNGUT_DATETIME FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG1 A, STRATA_PJ_BORANG4 B WHERE A.DAF_HM_NOFAIL = B.HM_DETAIL_NOFAIL),
            
        );

        END;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: @ezabeLharar what is the error you are gettig now ?

Comment: Thanks for your correction.  I corrected it and I got this error this time,Error report -
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at line 13
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:  Please anyone tell me where goes wrong?  and thanks to all who are trying to help me out here.....I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ezabeLharar tweak you the subquries written in the values clause such that it should writte only one value. Subqueris are the select queries you have written in values clause of insert statement.

Comment: (SELECT HM_DETAIL_NOTKT FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG4
            WHERE HM_DETAIL_NOTKT = c1rec.NO_TINGKAT

and the error is: ORA-00904: "C1REC"."NO_TINGKAT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 34 Column: 37

Comment: Error Invalid Identifier, we need to put database name, table or column? now, i need to put condition to migrate/copy data from strata to et_main_jozrin.  strata_pj_borang4 is table db strata

Comment: @ezabeLharar according to your comment you are getting error in "(SELECT HM_DETAIL_NOTKT FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG4 WHERE HM_DETAIL_NOTKT = c1rec.NO_TINGKAT)". This error suggest that either column "HM_DETAIL_NOTKT" or "HM_DETAIL_NOTKT"  does not exist in table STRATA_PJ_BORANG4 or you cursor variable "c1rec.NO_TINGKAT" is not correct. you cursor query should fetch column "NO_TINGKAT" from table HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL. Check where are you going wrong.

Comment: let me brief a bit the situation: source DB:STRATA, source table STRATA_PJ_BORANG4, source column: HM_DETAIL_NOTKT.  Target DB:ET_MAIN_WPPJ_JOZRIN, target table IND_HKMLK and target column NO_TINGKAT.  I need to migrate all data from source to target.  My issue now, I do not know how to write the condition when using SELECT.

Comment: if there is no condition, eg:SELECT HM_DETAIL_NOTKT FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG4, will be no problem.  now, I want to insert/copy the data row by row, i need condition, right? I am stuck there....i really appreciate from anybody guidance and teach.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not providing enough values compared to the number of columns you want to insert in. This happens, because the sub-selects are used for one column, not several. I've rewritten your statement as a single insert without loop. I'm using a CTE (common table expression) in order to put the logic in one place:

```
insert into ET_MAIN_WPPJ_JOZRIN.IND_HKMLK
(HKMLK_ID, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_BY, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, VERSION, 
            ID_HAKMILIK,NO_HAKMILIK, NO_BANGUNAN,NO_TINGKAT,NO_PETAK,UPI,FLAG_GANTUNG,
            FLAG_TUKARGANTI,TARIKH_KUTIPAN_ETANAH
)
with borang4_data as
(
select 
   SEQ_HKMLK.NEXTVAL                           HKMLK_ID,
   'DMS'                                       CREATED_BY,
   SYSDATE                                     CREATED_DATE,
   'DMS'                                       LAST_MODIFIED_BY,
   SYSDATE                                     LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
   '0'                                         VERSION,
   
   substr(borang4.HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL, 1, 17) ID_HAKMILIK,
   substr(borang4.HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL, -8)    NO_HAKMILIK,
      
   borang1.NO_BANGUNAN                         NO_BANGUNAN,
   borang1.NO_TINGKAT                          NO_TINGKAT,
   borang1.NO_PETAK                            NO_PETAK,
   borang1.UPI                                 UPI,
   borang1.FLAG_GANTUNG                        FLAG_GANTUNG,
   borang1.FLAG_TUKARGANTI                     FLAG_TUKARGANTI,
   borang1.TARIKH_KUTIPAN_ETANAH               TARIKH_KUTIPAN_ETANAH          

from PUTRAJAYA.STRATA_PJ_BORANG4 borang4

left join
   (SELECT HM_DETAIL_NOBGN                     NO_BANGUNAN,
           HM_DETAIL_NOTKT                     NO_TINGKAT,
           HM_DETAIL_NOPETAK                   NO_PETAK,
           HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL                UPI,
           'N'                                 FLAG_GANTUNG,
           'N'                                 FLAG_TUKARGANTI,
           HM_DETAIL_PUNGUT_DATETIME           TARIKH_KUTIPAN_ETANAH
      FROM STRATA_PJ_BORANG1) borang1
on borang1.DAF_HM_NOFAIL = borang4.HM_DETAIL_NOFAIL

WHERE borang4.HM_DETAIL_NOHMDETAIL is NOT NULL
)
select * from borang4_data;
```

I've made some assumptions regarding the joins looking at your code. Please verify if this works for you.